# How can I split a vector into smaller vectors of size N?

Tags: vector, rust

How to split a vector

```
let v: Vec<u8>; // vector with size x
```

into a vector of vectors of maxsize n? Pseudocode:

```
let n: usize = 1024;
let chunks_list: Vec<Vec<u8>> = chunks(v, n);
```

or using slices (to avoid copying):

```rust
let v: &[u8]; 
let chunks_list: Vec<&[u8]> = chunks(v, n);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Rust slices already contain the necessary method for that: [chunks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks).

Starting from this:

```
let src: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

you can get a vector of slices (no copy):

```
let dst: Vec<&[u8]> = src.chunks(3).collect();
```

or a vector of vectors (slower, heavier):

```
let dst: Vec<Vec<u8>> = src.chunks(3).map(|s| s.into()).collect();
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=49abd1c537842443fbd60ce86835227e)

Answer (score 4):

There is a method already existing for [slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks):

> `pub fn chunks(&self, chunk_size: usize) -> Chunks<'_, T>`
>
> Returns an iterator over `chunk_size` elements of the slice at a time, starting at the beginning of the slice.
> The chunks are slices and do not overlap. If `chunk_size` does not divide the length of the slice, then the last chunk will not have length `chunk_size`.

There is also [`chunks_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) for mutability as well as [`chunks_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact) and [`chunks_exact_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact_mut) if the last chunk has to respect the size `n`, along with the unsafe [`as_chunks_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_chunks_unchecked) in case we assume there is no remainder, see below example:

```
fn main() {
    let v: [u8; 5] = *b"lorem";
    let n = 2;
    let chunks = v.chunks(n);
    let chunks_list: Vec<&[u8]> = chunks.collect();
    println!("{:?}", chunks_list);
}
```

Using a slice instead of vectors has some [benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571441/what-is-the-difference-between-storing-a-vec-vs-a-slice), notably avoiding the overhead of copying.

Comment: You shouldn't jump directly to `as_chunks_unchecked` without using `as_chunks` or `array_chunks` first.

Answer (score 2):

If it's *required* to take a `Vec` and split it into multiple `Vec`s, I'd use [`Itertools::chunks`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks). This takes an iterator and returns an iterator of iterators. You can then choose to collect both the inner and outer iterators into `Vec`s:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.10.0

fn main() {
    let v = vec![String::from("A"), String::from("B"), String::from("C")];
    
    let x: Vec<Vec<String>> = v.into_iter().chunks(2).into_iter().map(|c| c.collect()).collect();
    
    eprintln!("{:?}", x);
}
```

```
[["A", "B"], ["C"]]
```

This has the benefit of taking ownership of each value in the original vector. No data needs to be *copied*, but it does need to be *moved*. If you can use slices instead, it's much better to use [`slice::chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```rust
use std::{usize, vec};

fn chunks(data: Vec<u8>, chunk_size: usize) -> Vec<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut results = vec![];
    let mut current = vec![];
    for i in data {
        if current.len() >= chunk_size {
            results.push(current);
            current = vec![];
        }
        current.push(i);
    }
    results.push(current);

    return results;
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<u8> = (1..100).collect();
    let n: usize = 24;
    let chunks_list = chunks(v, n);

    println!("{:#?}", chunks_list);
}
```