# How to stream a vector of bytes to BufWriter?

Tags: rust, tcp, stream, byte, buffer

I'm trying to stream bytes to a tcp server by using `io::copy(&mut reader, &mut writer)`, but it gives me this error: `the trait "std::io::Read" is not implemented for "Vec<{integer}>"`. Here I have a vector of bytes which would be the same as me opening a file and converting it to bytes. I want to write the bytes to the `BufWriter`. What am I doing wrong?

```rust
use std::io;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::BufWriter;

pub fn connect() {
    if let Ok(stream) = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080") {
        println!("Connection established!");
        let mut reader = vec![
            137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 70,
        ];
        let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);
        io::copy(&mut reader, &mut writer).expect("Failed to write to stream");
    } else {
        println!("Couldn't connect to the server")
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<{integer}>: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:12:31
   |
12 |         io::copy(&mut reader, &mut writer).expect("Failed to write to stream");
   |         --------              ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `Vec<{integer}>`
   |         |
   |         required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
note: required by a bound in `std::io::copy`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the compiler have a little trouble here, `Vec` doesn't implement `Read` but [`&[u8]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-2) do, you just have a get a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) from the vec before create a mutable reference:

```rust
copy(&mut reader.as_slice(), &mut writer).expect("Failed to write to stream");
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between storing a Vec vs a Slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571441/what-is-the-difference-between-storing-a-vec-vs-a-slice)
- [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Comment: Ok, what's a slice?

Comment: Now the server panics: `thread "main" panicked at "called "Result::unwrap()" on an "Err" value: Error { kind: InvalidData, message: "stream did not contain valid UTF-8" }"`. Isn't it possible to stream bytes to a tcp server?

Comment: @Nicke7117 that another problem with what you send I can't really help you there

Comment: @Nicke7117 It would be best to ask about your server panicking as a separate question.

Comment: @Nicke7117 _"What's a slice?"_ → https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/slice.html and https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `.as_slice()` like so works for me:

```rust
pub fn connect() {
    if let Ok(stream) = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080") {
        println!("Connection established!");
        let reader = vec![
            137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 70,
        ];
        let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);
        io::copy(&mut reader.as_slice(), &mut writer).expect("Failed to write to stream");
    } else {
        println!("Couldn't connect to the server")
    }
}
```

That’s because [std::io::Read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) supports slices.